# Overwriting arguments object for a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments, conventions

If I have the following:

```
    // Clean input.
    $.each(arguments, function(index, value) {

        arguments[index] = value.replace(/[\W\s]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    });
```

Would that be a bad thing to do? I have no further use for the uncleaned arguments in the function, and it would be nice not to create a useless copy of `arguments` just to use them, but are there any negative effects to doing this?

Ideally I would have done this, but I'm guessing this runs into problems since `arguments` isn't really an Array:

```
    arguments = $.map(arguments, function(value) {

        return value.replace(/[\W\s]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    });
```

Thanks for any input.

EDIT: I've just realized that both of these are now inside their own functions, so the arguments object has changed. Any way to do this without creating an unnecessary variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not have thought that `arguments[i] = value;` works, because of the same reason (it is not a real array).

You really should consider to assign the cleaned values to a new variable:

```
var cleaned_args = $.map(arguments, function(value) {
    return value.replace(/[\W\s]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
});
```

Introducing a new variable here is not unnecessary. Most often you don't directly operate on `arguments` anyway (because of its shortcomings like the one you already discovered), but convert it to a real array first (which will involve a new variable anyway).

**Regarding your edit:**

Right, the first one would not work because `arguments` refers to the arguments of the anonymous function.

Comment: Yeah, you can update the values in an Arguments object just like you can update the value of a formal parameter. (They're the same thing. The formal parameters are mapped internally to the Arguments object.) But if OP ultimately wanted to further manipulate the arguments as a collection, then converting to an Array with `$.map` is the way to go.