# Is manipulating the arguments object a good idea?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm writing a meteor helper function, which has the quirk that the last argument to the function is always in the form of `{hash: {"name":"objectICareAbout"}}`. I'm trying to write a flexible helper which can be called in several different ways, so I want to unwrap the last argument.

In order to avoid writing a check for each argument, I've written this simple line to unwrap the final argument:

```
arguments[arguments.length - 1] = arguments[arguments.length - 1].hash;
```

JSHint throws an error at this point, but in looking around I can't see any real reason not to do this.

Is this line safe? Are there any quirks to worry about, or should it work as expected everywhere?

Comment: How are you using the arguments object later? `otherFn.apply(this, arguments)` or soemthing?

Comment: No, I was just using the arguments object as a shorthand way to unwrap the last argument. However, as per @richsilv's answer I'll probably just just convert the arguments object to an array and then get my method parameters from there.

Comment: It's absolutely fine to do this, but you'll get a performance penalty. Modifying arguments is safe and is consistent -- It's been specced for a long time (ES3)

Comment: It is safe to modify the arguments, but it can lead to unexpected results, see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d519rs43/). You could do `[].slice.call(arguments)` to disconnect it.

Comment: @adeneo as richsilv pointed out, you can only expect the linked argument-arguments behavior if you do not 'use strict' (see updated filddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oddc8071/1/), since I want my code to be usable in either environment I opted to unpack the arguments object into an array as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will probably work in your browser, but it shouldn't work when JS is run in strict mode - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433554/is-this-legal-javascript-passing-arguments-to-function-and-having-it-change-the) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000758/overwriting-arguments-object-for-a-javascript-function) - which is presumably why JSHint doesn't like it.

As per megawac's comment, it depends what you're doing with the arguments afterwards, but I think unpacking them into a new object/array is probably a better idea.